# How to do quick symbolic integration in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

```
  ClearAll["Global`*"];
    Clear[b]
    L = 4;
    z1 = L/3;
    z2 = (2*L)/3;
    Y = 2*10^11;
    b=3.14;
    Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
    A = 0.1^2;
    kb = (Y*Iyy)/L^3
    W1 = A1*Sin[b*x] + B1*Cos[b*x] + C1*Sinh[b*x] + E1*Cosh[b*x];
    W2 = A2*Sin[b*x] + B2*Cos[b*x] + C2*Sinh[b*x] + E2*Cosh[b*x];
    W3 = A3*Sin[b*(x - z2)] + B3*Cos[b*(x - z2)] + C3*Sinh[b*(x - z2)] + E3*Cosh[b*(x-z2)];
    W=Piecewise[{{W1, x <= z1}, {W2, z1 <= x <= z2}, {W3, x >= z2}}];
    Wxx = D[W, {x, 2}]
    s1 = 0.5*Iyy*Y*Integrate[(Wxx)^2, {x, 0, L}];
```

Assuming `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,.....E1,E2,E3` are `Reals`. How can we reduce the integration time? This takes too much time. I want to overcome this difficulty.

Is there any shortcut for carrying out this integration? I used some commands.

1. `FullSimplify`
2. `Expand`
3. `TrigReduce`

Everything is going smoothly only the integration is taking too much time. I have reduced the code now.

Comment: `Integrate` has the option `Assumtions` which allows to tell Mathematica about certain propertie sof variables, for example `Element[A1, Reals]&&Element[A2, Reals]&&...` and so on. Sometimes that helps.

Comment: Also using only exact numbers (see also `Rationalize`) and performing the indefinite integral `Integrate[(Wxx)^2, x]` first often help as in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
int = PiecewiseExpand[Integrate[(Wxx)^2, x]];
0.5*Iyy*Y*((int /. x -> L) - (int /. x -> 0)) // Expand
```